# # of records loaded through AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-data-pipeline

Is there a way through the AWS console to understand the number of records that got loaded into a redshift table using the AWS data pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that information from [`STL_LOAD_COMMITS`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_COMMITS.html) table.

Especially look at `lines_scanned` column:

> Number of lines scanned from the load file. This number may not match the number of rows that are actually loaded. For example, the load may scan but tolerate a number of bad records, based on the MAXERROR option in the COPY command.

Like

```
SELECT * FROM STL_LOAD_COMMITS
ORDER BY curtime DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: MAXERROR should always be set to zero, as a matter of good practise.  Incoming files should either fully load, or not load at all.  The complexity which comes from *partial* loads is practically impossible to justify.